# ¿Cómo dividir una cadena usando el método re.split() sin eliminar los símbolos usados ​como separadores?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, regex, split

```py
import re

input_text = "los gorriones , asdjjhsadjhsad ; hhjasdhjsda . djfjdfjhdf , hdhgsdhg \n hjdsfjhjdf"

separators = r"(?:\.\n|\n|\.|;|,|$)"

separators_pattern = f"({separators})"
result_list = re.split(separators_pattern, input_text)

# Remove empty items in the list
result_list = [x for x in result_list if x]

# Concatenates each separator with its corresponding element
result_list = [result_list[i] + result_list[i+1] for i in range(0, len(result_list)-1, 2)]

# Check if the last part of the input text is in the result list and add it if necessary
if input_text.endswith(result_list[-1]):
    result_list[-1] = input_text.rstrip()

print(result_list) # --> output list
```

¿Por qué al usar este código Python, **la última parte de la cadena no aparece en la lista resultante** ?

Desde que uso el código que he colocado en la pregunta, obtengo esta lista incompleta:

```
['los gorriones ,', ' asdjjhsadjhsad ;', ' hhjasdhjsda .', ' djfjdfjhdf ,', ' hdhgsdhg \n']
```

El objetivo sería poder obtener una lista completa como esta lista:

```
['los gorriones ,', ' asdjjhsadjhsad ;', ' hhjasdhjsda .', ' djfjdfjhdf ,', ' hdhgsdhg \n', ' hjdsfjhjdf']
```

El problema con esta pregunta es que estoy usando diferentes tipos de separadores y tengo que mantenerlos dentro de las cadenas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En esta comprensión de lista se van tomando dos elementos a la vez de la lista:

```
result_list = [result_list[i] + result_list[i+1] for i in range(0, len(result_list)-1, 2)]
```

Si la lista es impar, queda un último elemento sin procesar.

Una manera de resolver el problema es agregar siempre un elemento adicional a la lista de entrada. Eso asegura que no haya elementos huérfanos al final de la lista:

```
result_list = [x for x in result_list if x]
result_list.append('')
```

Con este cambio, se hace innecesario el chequeo final

```
if input_text.endswith(result_list[-1]):
    result_list[-1] = input_text.rstrip()
```

#### Demo

```
import re

input_text = "los gorriones , asdjjhsadjhsad ; hhjasdhjsda . djfjdfjhdf , hdhgsdhg \n hjdsfjhjdf"

separators = r"(?:\.\n|\n|\.|;|,|$)"

separators_pattern = f"({separators})"
result_list = re.split(separators_pattern, input_text)

# Remove empty items in the list
result_list = [x for x in result_list if x]
result_list.append('')

# Concatenates each separator with its corresponding element
result_list = [result_list[i] + result_list[i+1] for i in range(0, len(result_list)-1, 2)]
    
print(result_list) # --> output list
```

produce:

```
['los gorriones ,', ' asdjjhsadjhsad ;', ' hhjasdhjsda .', ' djfjdfjhdf ,', ' hdhgsdhg \n', ' hjdsfjhjdf']

Process finished with exit code 0
```